# Wordpress items not aligning properly under title

Tags: css, wordpress, widget, alignment

My website is [www.20watt.nl](http://www.20watt.nl)

One of the 3 wordpress footer-widgets ("blog & nieuws") displays my latest blog entries, but the entries are not aligning properly under the widget title. The dropdown menu entries (under "informatie" do the same thing)

I've tried to find out what's causing it in style.css, but so far haven't figured it out.

Any help is appreciated & many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Padding is being applied to the UL element. As can be seen here in Chrome inspect element:

[image: As can be seen here via Chrome Inspect Element]

Add `padding: 0` to `.footer-widget ul`.

And add the same thing to `#site-navigation .dropdown-menu ul` for your nav.